# ¿Por que al usar el operador Bash <= me da "error sintáctico: se esperaba un operando"?

Tags: bash

Tengo la siguiente línea:

```
for (( NUM=1; NUM<=${NUM_LIGHTS}; NUM++ ))
```

al ejecutarla en consola me funciona correctamente, pero al ejecutar mediante un script me aparece el siguiente error con el operador **<=**

> línea 15: ((: NUM >=  : error sintáctico: se esperaba un operando (el elemento de error es ">=  ")

¿Qué es erróneo?

Comment: Y si cambias `${NUM_LIGHTS}` por `$NUM_LIGHTS`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

falta asignar un valor a NUM_LIGHTS.

Antes del for puedes escribir :

```
 NUM_LIGHTS=5
```

(o el valor que corresponda) y el error desaparecerá.
Si no ha sido asignado, la sustitución deja:

```
   for (( NUM=1; NUM<= ; NUM++ ))
```

y le falta un operando para la comparación, que es lo que dice el mensaje.

Comment: no tenia el valor en el script. Gracias!